Elasticsearch aggregation AND and OR
Im looking for some help with Aggregates in my query. Overall i got it running pretty for however it is excluding data and im maybe using the wrong approach here. In my dataset i have an key called "productwaarden" that is a nested object. Inside this i hold data like this:
Document 1:
[
    {
        "zoekbaar": false,
        "waarde": "BOL",
        "naam": "Leerweg",
        "filterbaar": true
    },
    {
        "zoekbaar": false,
        "waarde": "2",
        "naam": "Foo",
        "filterbaar": true
    }
]

Document 2:
[
  {
    "zoekbaar": false,
    "waarde": "BBL",
    "naam": "Leerweg",
    "filterbaar": true
  },
  {
    "zoekbaar": false,
    "waarde": "1",
    "naam": "Foo",
    "filterbaar": true
  }
]

The requirement i have is that when i filter on a naam with a waarde here. So for instance i select all BOL values. The aggregate should behave as an OR and not as an AND. The AND should be done over the naam key.  For instance, when i select BOL as filter, both BOL and BBL should be in my aggregate result. When i select BOL only, the value for Foo should be only 2 since 1 is not matching on that document.
This is the query i have at this point:
{
  "aggs": {
    "productwaarden.nested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "productwaarden"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "productwaarden.filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "term": {
                  "productwaarden.filterbaar": true
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "naam": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "productwaarden.naam.aggregate",
                "size": 1000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "waarde": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "productwaarden.waarde.aggregate",
                    "size": 1000
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "productwaarden",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "productwaarden.naam.aggregate": "Leerweg"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "productwaarden.waarde.aggregate": ["BBL"]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Thanks in advance
EDIT:
Example how the UI looks. As you can seen in the ui the group "Leerweg" has 2 entries here. Both "BBL" and "BOL". When i select "BBL" here i do want to exclude it from my query results but not from my aggregate. Inside those groups it should be an OR.
UI view

Could you please provide an example of how the result should look? Its difficult understanding with the text only.

@Usama, i added an image how the UI looks. I think this will clarify it a bit more
